# Examples of operating systems capable of serving http-requests that does not support direct slash for directory separator

Tags: web, operating-systems, cross-platform, portability

My php framework uses `DIRECORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `/`. Can there be any other options for a directory separator?

Answer (score 5):

On MacOS, the directory separator is `:`, on Windows, it is `\`, and on VMS, it is `.`.

MacOS is no longer in use, though. OSX uses `/`, but continues to support `:`. Windows largely supports `/`, although for some APIs, you *must* use `\`.

Answer (score -1):

Of the popular software today there are only two different directory seperators: / and \ . Windows being the one using \ also happens to support / of all the api's and command line tools accepting a file path as argument.

I have often on windows used / as a seperator from both Java and .NET code and I have never experienced any trouble.

To answer your question. There are no examples of operating systems in use today that doesn't support / as directory seperator.